# Which Thread.sleep commands pauses which threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I have four declarations of Thread.sleep(...) below. Each of the declarations is marked with that *Line #1 to #6*. My question is which declarations put which threads to pause?

```
class Runa extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        try{
            // Line #1
            Thread.sleep(500);
            //Line #2
            this.sleep(500);
        }catch(Exception e) {}
    }
}

class Runb implements Runnable {
    Thread t;

    Runb() {
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();

        try{
            //Line #3
            Thread.sleep(500);

        }catch(Exception e){ }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
     
        try {
            do {

                // Line #4
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                // Line #5
                // t.sleep(500);
                count++;
            } while (count < 10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }

    }
}

public class thread2Runnable2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {          
        Runa rua = new Runa();
        rua.start();
        //Line #6
        rua.sleep(500); 
       
        Runb runb = new Runb();    
    }
}
```

These are my assumptions:

```
Line #1 pause Runa thread
Line #2 pause Runa thread
Line #3 pause the main thread
Line #4 pause t thread
Line #5 pause t thread
Line #6 pause the main thread
```

Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: `rua.sleep();` <--- you need a number of milliseconds as the parameter, don't you?

Comment: Sorry I'm using a tab. This devices is killing me.

Comment: I would say your assumptions are correct. BTW, `Runa rua = new Thread();` won't compile. Also, `Runb() { t = new Thread(this); t.start(); }` could lead to the classic case of **Escaped Reference**. Avoid such initializations.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(long)` is a static method which sleeps the _current thread_. The current thread is the one executing the code. So whichever thread invokes `sleep` is the one that sleeps. As far as I can tell your assumptions appear correct.

Comment: Did you mean `Thread rua = new Runa();` otherwise `Runa rua = new Thread();` won't compile.

Comment: Thanks @Slaw. Your explanation just hit it. Could you kindly answer it. So I can close it.

Comment: yes, you are correct. By debugging it (and giving names to the threads) you could easily check it

Comment: This is from a technical interview for a mid level. But the class I'm showing here is different but the behavior resembles the questions. Hopefully it can also be useful for future readers.

Comment: Those are not _declarations_ of `Thread.sleep()`, those are _calls to_ `Thread.sleep()`. If you want to see the declaration, that's in the source file, `.../java/lang/Thread.java`.

Comment: @Slaw, I always try to avoid saying "current thread," when talking to newbies. Which thread is the _current_ thread when you've got eight CPUs, and they're all busy? The phrase, "current thread" comes from a time long gone when there were no multi-CPU system, and unfortunately, we seem to be stuck with it. I tell noobs, "Every time you see 'current thread,' you should read it as if it said, 'the caller.'"

Comment: @SolomonSlow Interesting. Maybe it's because I grew up with multi-core/multi-processor computers being the norm, but in my mind "current thread" has always been completely synonymous with "the calling thread".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Thread#sleep(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) method is a *static* method which:

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers.

The currently executing thread is the thread which invoked the method. So whichever thread invokes `sleep` is the one which sleeps. As far as I can tell, your assumptions appear correct.

Answer (score 5):

[Thread.sleep()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) is a static method, so it doesn't matter which object you call it on: it will always act on the currently executing thread.

The fact that you can call this method on an instance (e.g. `runa`) syntax-wise at all is a quirk of Java and can be very confusing. Many IDEs and other code-quality tools will highlight such calls as warnings as the object reference is completely irrelevant to the call and thus can be misleading to someone reading the code.

If you use the normal static call syntax, `Thread.sleep(NNNN)`, you see that no object reference is passed, which, even without reading the documentation, easily leads to the conclusion that the only reasonable behavior is to act on current thread.

Comment: Yes invoking .sleep() through a thread instance but eventually pausing another thread is quite confusing sometimes.